# Mutate and format multiple date columns

Tags: r, datetime, date-manipulation

I have a `tibble` containing some date columns formatted as strings:

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-tibble(dates1 = c("2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
           dates2 = c("2020-08-05T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-05T00:00:00.000Z"))
```

I want to convert the strings from YMD-HMS to DMY-HMS. Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("dates")), as.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Whereas this does?

```
df %>% mutate(dates1 = format(as.Date(dates1),  "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  mutate(dates2 = format(as.Date(dates2),  "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Finally, is it possible to assign these columns as 'datetime' columns (e.g. dttm) rather than `chr` once the date formatting has taken place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` argument which you are passing is for `as.Date` whereas what you really want is to pass it for `format` function. You can use an anonymous function for that or use formula syntax.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("dates"), ~format(as.Date(.), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  dates1              dates2             
#  <chr>               <chr>              
#1 03/08/2020 00:00:00 05/08/2020 00:00:00
#2 03/08/2020 00:00:00 05/08/2020 00:00:00
```

To represent data as date or datetime R uses standard way of representing them which is `Y-M-D H:M:S`, you can change the representation using `format` but then the output would be character as above.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("dates"), lubridate::ymd_hms))

#  dates1              dates2             
#  <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1 2020-08-03 00:00:00 2020-08-05 00:00:00
#2 2020-08-03 00:00:00 2020-08-05 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with regards to `format`, Ronak. For my particular application, I have to output the data as DMY-HMS (other software requires the date in this format). I'm guessing I can't represent the data as DMY-HMS within R? It sounds like the column type _has_ to be `chr` if I want to display it as DMY-HMS?

Comment: Yes, that is true. If you want data in the format `DMY-HMS` it will be character.