# unexpected error - format datetime into mutate

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I was following the clue:
[Mutate and format multiple date columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581912/mutate-and-format-multiple-date-columns/63582008#63582008)

The solution results in an error

```
M601_M_multi.2 <- M601_M_multi %>% 
  mutate (
    across(ends_with(' Time'), ~format(as.POSIXct(.), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")),
                 .names = "{.col}.used")   
  )
```

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(contains(" Time"), ~format(as.POSIXct(.), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `C3_S1_O2_PV Time`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`
```

In df I have numerous columns where the name ends with " Time". I want to convert all to date and time (as.POSIXct)

The single column solution works though

```
M601_M_multi.2 <- M601_M_multi %>% 
  mutate (
    test = as.POSIXct(`C3_S1_O2_PV Time`, format ="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")    
  )
```

Any suggestion and answer will be appreciated

Comment: The single column operation is different ... Can you please post some data e.g. by using `dput(head(M601_M_multi))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code blocks are not equivalent.

```r
  mutate (
    across(ends_with(' Time'), ~format(as.POSIXct(.), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")),
                 .names = "{.col}.used")   
  )
```

The code sequence:

- `as.POSIXct(x)`, using the default `format=`, which is to try some unambiguous formats embedded within the function. Notably missing from the list of `tryFormats=` is anything including `"%d.%m.%Y ..."`.
- Convert *back* to a string with `format(y, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")`. This assumes that `y` here already inherits from `POSIXt`, so that this makes sense. This expression should result in *strings* (`character` class), not number-like timestamps (`POSIXt` class).

In your second block:

```r
  mutate (
    test = as.POSIXct(`C3_S1_O2_PV Time`, format ="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")    
  )
```

The code sequence:

- `as.POSIXct(x, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")` is *correct* (I think) in that you know that `x` here is not in an unambiguous format, so you are telling `as.POSIXct` how to find specific components of the timestamp. This should result in a number-like `POSIXt`-class object.

I think you need your code to be:

```r
  mutate(
    across(ends_with(' Time'), ~ as.POSIXct(., format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"),
           .names = "{.col}.used")   
  )
```

which results in new columns (with `.used` appended to the names) filled with `POSIXt`-class values.